# unique config.json for grunt uglify

Tags: json, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

Hi I'm trying to make a config.json, that feeds the uglify with src-files, so we easily can include/exclude files, based on the nature of the project.
I would like to use the projects name (<%= pkg.name %>) to give a unique name to the config.json as the example below, but this isn't working. Any clues to a solution?

```
    uglify: {
     ....
       files: {
          'assets/js/default.min.js': grunt.file.readJSON( 'assets/js/config-<%= pkg.name %>.json' )
          }
       }
    },
```

Example of the config.json:

**[

```
"assets/js/vendor/jquery.js",
"assets/js/vendor/jquery.cookie.js",
"assets/js/vendor/bootstrap-alert.js",
"assets/js/vendor/bootstrap-button.js",
"assets/js/vendor/bootstrap-carousel.js",
"assets/js/vendor/bootstrap-collapse.js",
"assets/js/vendor/bootstrap-affix.js",
"assets/js/vendor/blueimp-gallery.js",
```

]**

Answer (score 0):

```
uglify: {
     ....
       files: {
          'assets/js/default.min.js': 'assets/js/config-<%= pkg.name %>.json'
          }
       }
    },
```

should work without the need of manually reading the JSON file

Comment: Hey thanks - but not working - I have updated the question. I need to read the json in my config.json. The above example is working if I name my file config.json and the same in the readJSON path, but I want to be able to have unique name (version control)